# Deploy artifacts with jgitflow to the non-default nexus server

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I've a jgitflow setup. The Nexus URL is defined in a profile in a root pom from which the local pom inherits. Now I want to overwrite the URL using my jgitflow maven command.
How can I do this? (I can not edit the pom):

I tried something like:

```
jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish -Durl=https://server/nexus/ -Pprofiles ..
```

I also tried

```
jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish -DaltDeploymentRepository=name::default::https://url
```

It didn't work,  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Considering [issue MJF-273](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-273?filter=-4&jql=project%20%3D%20MJF%20AND%20text%20~%20%22url%22%20order%20by%20created%20DESC), try simply (for testing) to change the urk of the remote `origin` in your Git configuration, and see if it is picked up by your next mvn command:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/git/repo
git remote set-url origin https://alternative/server/url
mvn -DdevelopmentVersion=0.2.2-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=0.2.1 -B jgitflow:release-start -X
```

Note: the -X will give you more details on the error message that you have.

Comment: Will this update my nexus (deploy) url or the git repo url? I need to update the nexus url. I can try tomorrow.

Comment: Git repo URL, just for testing and see if it has priority over the pom.